# What is the difference between this 3 type of ArrayList declaration

Tags: java, arraylist

i don't know if i ask this question in right way or not , but really i don't know if  this 3 is equal or not ?

1. `ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();`
2. `ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList();`
3. `ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: 1 and 3 essentially mean the same thing. 1 is just a shorted way of writing 3 but as far as I know, 1 will work only from Java SE 8 and not before.

2. doesn't do anything and it just creates an ArrayList of objects and not Strings. You need explicitly mention the generics on both ends in declaration like 1 or 3.

Comment: @ArunSubramanian The `<>` diamond operator was [added in Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html), and all 3 do the same thing: Given type-erasure at runtime, they create an `ArrayList` for storing `Object` instances. #2 will generate an "unchecked conversion" compile-time warning.